# Как очистить форму после отправки

Tags: javascript

Есть форма.Как только не пытался юзать reset-толку нет.Либо ошибка, либо не очищается форма.Как можно очистить все поля внутри формы?!
Вот код :

```js
jQuery('#contact-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var c_name = jQuery('#c_name').val();
  var c_email = jQuery('#c_email').val();
  var c_message = jQuery('#c_message ').val();
  var response = jQuery('#contact-form .ajax-response');
  var formData = {
    'name': c_name,
    'email': c_email,
    'message': c_message
  };
  if ((c_name == '' || c_email == '' || c_message == '') || (!isValidEmailAddress(c_email))) {
    response.fadeIn(500);
    response.html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Исправьте ошибки в форме и попробуйте снова.');
  } else {
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
      url: 'php/contact.php', // the url where we want to POST
      data: formData, // our data object
      dataType: 'json', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
      encode: true,
      success: function(res) {
        var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(res));
        response.html(ret.message).fadeIn(500);
      }
    });
    response.html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Ваше сообщение отправлено, Спасибо за Ваш Выбор!');
  }
  return false;
});
```

Пробовал после отправки обращаться к #contact-form, но ничего не выходит.

Comment: В succes добавьте очистку.

Comment: success: function(res) {
    ...
    alert('проверка');
  } Попробовал даже так сделать-алерт не срабатывает

Comment: Значит у вас отправка не успешная.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, как она может быть не успешной,если письмо приходит на почту?!

Comment: Например вы возвращаете не верный http код.

Comment: @МстиславПавлов, А что должно вернуться?!

Comment: Я разобрался.Я получал не тот тип данных от сервера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  success: function(res) {
    ...
    jQuery('#contact-form')[0].reset();
  }
```

Comment: Вот я тоже так думал.Но не срабатывает-ошибок нет.А сегодня меня посетила умная мысль и я просто вставил алерт что бы проверить-и он не выполняется внутри success...ошибок в консоле нет.В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Добавьте обработчик `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + " - " + errorThrown + ": " + jqXHR.responseText) }` в `jQuery.ajax` параметр.

Answer (score 0):

Например: можно сделать двумя способам, первый это до каждого поля добавить класс (например `.reset`) и по классу очищать поля все сразу

```
$('.reset').val('');
```

или очищать каждое поле отдельно.

```
$('#c_name').val('');
$('#c_email').val('');
$('#c_message').val('');
```

Етот код нужно вставлять в середину функции `res`.

```
success: function(res) {
      $('.reset').val('');
    var ret = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(res));
    response.html(ret.message).fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: У меня почему то не срабатывает даже алерт внутри res.Так ведь не должно быть.Верно?