# Очистка формы после отправки

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

Доброго дня! Есть некоторая форма, которая `<form action='server.php' id='cl_form' method='POST' target='_blank'>`. Мне надо очистить форму после передачи данных на `server.php`. Всякие `onsubmit` и `$('#cl_form').submit(...)` вызываются до отправки и я не понимаю как вызвать что-то после отправки.

Comment: Если не критично, что форма будет очищаться всегда, попробуйте при загрузке страницы очистить форму. Т.е. в *onload* добавить **document.getElementById("cl_form").reset()**;

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Я использую `target='_blank'`

Comment: Это не важно. Вы при загрузке вашей странички, где находится ваша форма *id='cl_form'*, очищайте эту форму.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko дело в том, что я отправляю сообщение, форма обрабатывает в новой вкладке и закрывает ее после обработки. Мы основную страницу с формой не перезагружаем, а значит и onload не вызовется.

Comment: Ага, ну тогда есть вариант с таймаутом. Поставьте на событие *onsubmit* `setTimeout(resetForm,500)`. Конечно, не самое элегантное решение)

Comment: копайте в сторону двухсторонней связи между окнами и событиями обьекта `window`, в частности метода `open`. @StepanKasyanenko не извращяйтесь

Comment: @ddeadlink ну ведь шутка в том, что у ТС окно открывается не методом `open`. Способов получить событие из другого окна, открытым через `target='_blank'` вроде бы нету.

Answer (score 1):

После отправки данных вам надо вызвать метод reset() у формы.

Пример:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

[Документация](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_reset.asp)

[Вот решение:](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483721/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: Вы не ответили на вопрос: как это сделать **после** отправки?

Comment: К сожалению, пробовал это в первую очередь, но форма чистится до отправки

Comment: Вот так:     `success: function(res) {
    ...
    jQuery('#contact-form')[0].reset();
  }`

Comment: @Swartex Если я отправляю форму через action, не думаю, что ajax стоит вызывать для повторной отправки.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "{{ __('This field is required.') }}",
})

$('#cl_form').validate({
    rules: {
        title: {
            required: true,
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form)
    {
        form.submit();
        document.getElementById("cl_form").reset();
    }
});
</script>
```